# How to get a list of counts of records in SQL?

Tags: sql

(Warning, I'm a Java guy, not a SQL guy ... :) trying to do something in SQL that's puzzling me ...

Simplified example: I have an `ACTIVE_USERS` table (with a `USER_ID` and a `ACTIVE_DATE` they became active).  There is a `USERS` table (with a `ID`, `USERNAME`, and `GROUP_ID` for the group they belong to).  And there is a `USERGROUP` table (with a `ID` and a `GROUP_NAME`).

I want to get a list of the Groups with the number of users in each group (for a given date range).

What I have so far:

```
select distinct USER_ID, USERNAME, GROUP_NAME
from ACTIVE_USERS
INNER JOIN USERS 
ON ACTIVE_USERS.USER_ID=USER.ID
INNER JOIN USERGROUP
ON USER.GROUP_ID=GROUP.ID
where 
ACTIVE_USER.ACTIVE_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-DEC-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD') AND TO_DATE('2017-JAN-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
AND
USERGROUP.ID=3006648
```

This gets me the list of distinct users for a specific USERGROUP (3006648).

And if I change the first line to:

```
select count(distinct USER_ID) ...
```

That gets me the count.

Not sure what to do next ... do I make this code into a function or something and pass my dates and group id in as parameters?

Comment: can you tag the dbms being used?

Comment: FYI, `GROUP` is a reserved keyword in SQL so if you had a table with that name, you would normally have to "quote" the name so that the SQL parser did not throw an error.  The `GROUP` keyword is used for exactly the thing that you are trying to do ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks -- updated GROUP to USERGROUP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be wanting the *amazing* SQL `GROUP BY` operation.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) User_count, GROUP_NAME
  ... the rest of your query .... leaving out WHERE GROUP.ID=3006648 ...
  GROUP BY GROUP_NAME
```

By the way, this line

```
  /*wrong*/   ACTIVE_USER.ACTIVE_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-DEC-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD') AND TO_DATE('2017-JAN-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

contains a notorious off-by-one error. BETWEEN is bad for datetime matches because it's inclusive.  You really want this to get everything in December.

```
    ACTIVE_USER.ACTIVE_TIME >= TO_DATE('2016-DEC-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD') 
AND ACTIVE_USER.ACTIVE_TIME <  TO_DATE('2017-JAN-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

This will pick up `2016-12-31 23:59.59` and reject `2017-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks for adding the date-related tip in addition to the answer, helped greatly.